# Footer occasionally rendering over overlay on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that has a sticky footer, scrolling content, and an overlay that renders after being on the page for a couple of seconds. I am seeing an issue on Safari where sometimes on some devices (iPhone 12 - 15) the footer and some part of the scrolling content overlap the bottom part of the overlay. It doesn't happen consistently, and it only happens on Safari, which is leading me to believe it's not an issue with the css, but rather something where the scroll changes the height of the container. However, it looks like the overlay content is still set to take up the full screen, and when the content renders on top it cuts off the bottom part of the overlay. All of them are within the body

```
<body style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; height: unset;">
  <div class="page">
     <main style="display: block;">
        <div class="content" style="position: relative; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
           <div class="footer" style="display: block; width: 100%; left: 0; bottom: 0; position: fixed; pointer-events: auto;">...</div>
           <div class="scroll_content" style="max-width: 100vw; overflow: hidden;">...</div>
        </div>
     </main>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 100vw; height: 100%; z-index: 9223372036854776000 !important;">..</div>
</body>
```

Could there be some situation where sometimes Safari renders things in different order? I'm totally lost because I can't easily replicate it and I can't tell what exactly would cause it, so any insight would be appreciated!

Sorry for the photo, again it's tough to reproduce so had to make up a similar scenario :)[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "the footer and some part of the scrolling content overlap the bottom part of the overlay"

Comment: @SpencerMay Added an image to try to clarify a bit

Answer (score 0):

Positioning can cause all sorts of issues when stacked like that, try restructuring your containers in a more logical way to approach the template...insert your html here and go to town

```css
    /*
        make sure your viewport is the full screen with no padding or margin
    */
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    /*
        your new scrolling container will be the full height of your screen, full width by default of a div
        box-sizing: border-box will save you later by treating the padding and margins as INCLUDED in the total width of this page
    */
    .page {
        height: 100%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background-color: green;
    }
    /*
        your footer now exists OUTSIDE of your scrolling page, sticky to bottom of the screen at z-index: 1
    */
    .footer {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    /*
        your overlay also sits outside of your scrolling page fixed to the viewport at z-index: 2 so that it's above the footer
        added opacity to see behind the overlay
    */
    #overlay {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: pink;
        opacity: 30%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="page">
    This should be your scroll content
    <p style="height: 2000px;">Force overflow</p>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    This is your footer, since it's fixed, it still exists outside of the overlay
</div>
<div id="overlay">
    <br /><br /><br /><br />This overlay exists above and outside of the scroll content, although with opacity. You may need to remove it to scroll
</div>
```